# NotInTransactionException when adding item to a HashSet<E>

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

#### EDIT

> Since I got no answer at the moment and the github Ticket I opened has
> been closed, I'll create an example on github to reproduce the bug to
> find what's the problem. Once the problem will be fixed, I'll add my
> own answer to this question to provide a real solution.

First of all, I reported this as an [issue on SDN's Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/316).

Anyways, I post my problem here to see if someone has the solution.

So, I have one Player model :

```
@NodeEntity
public class Player {

    @GraphId Long id;
    String name;

    String email;

    @Transient
    String password;

    int elo = 1200;
    
    @RelatedTo(type="FRIEND_WITH", direction = Direction.BOTH)
    Set<Player> friends = new HashSet<Player>();

    //After this I have Getters and Setters
    //no need to paste them all I guess
}
```

and its repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="player", path="player")
public interface PlayerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Player, Long> {
}
```

I created two players, using POST requests, and verified they were really created using GET.

Then I want to add player 0 as friend of player 1:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/uri-list' -d 'localhost:8080/api/player/1' http://localhost:8080/api/player/0/friends
```

And I get an exception:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 16:20:24 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "timestamp" : "2015-11-09T16:20:24.844+0000",
  "status" : 500,
  "error" : "Internal Server Error",
  "exception" : "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException",
  "message" : "No message available",
  "path" : "/api/player/0/friends"
}
```

To see the complete stack trace, please check the Github link at the top of the question, it's too long to be read-able here.

Just in case, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.afkgames</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-rest-sdn</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>api.Bootstrap</start-class>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
       <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <name>Neo4j</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

EDIT:
I tried to add @Transactional on my repository interface, it failed with the same error.

Comment: Can you try to add a @Transactional to your repository method

Comment: @MichaelHunger I've tried it, edited topic to add the answer, but it did not work :/ got exactly the same exception

Comment: Yore're using POST in the curl call, that means it's creating something new thus it probably needs transaction. Can you post your REST method and the corresponding DAO method  called for the POST? findByName will most likely be called in a REST GET method not in POST so it's code doesn't much help with the debugging the issue.

Comment: Those methods are created by spring-rest, in fact, I created the findByname method just for a test, everything works fine without this method.

Comment: For the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version, try using "1.3.0.RELEASE".

Comment: You should also change some other parts of the POM file to use the release version. I will updated my answer.

Comment: I created a github project to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/Supamiu/sdn4-Issue316-demo feel free to clone it and try by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

Try updating your POM file to use the 1.3.0.RELEASE version of the Spring framework. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.afkgames</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-rest-sdn</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>api.Bootstrap</start-class>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <name>Neo4j</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: as I replied in the comments, the findByName method is here only for a test, I can delete it, the api will work fine. I'll edit the question to delete the method signature in the interface, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Updated my answer to suggest using the 1.3.0.RELEASE version of the Spring framework.

Comment: Nothing changed, still the same problem with RELEASE

Comment: can i get a github link of your project,any demo which you are working on,it will be easy to debug

Comment: @PrabjotSingh sorry for being late, I had no notification since this is not my reply ^^" here is the link you are looking for: https://github.com/Supamiu/sdn4-Issue316-demo